# Google maps API json_decode not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to do something relatively simple, making a request between two postcodes to google and taking the returned JSON decoding and using it within my app.

Except the json_decode is oddly failing, even though it is valid json in my opinion.

Anyone come across this before? Code below:

```
    $url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:CM96YS%20to:CM96SN';

    $data = @file_get_contents($url);
    echo $data;

    $data = json_decode($data);

    var_dump($data);
```

Comment: If you're looking to get driving directions from Google, you should use the [Driving Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) instead.

Comment: I agree with Mano.  You should be using the Google Maps Directions API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure Mano is right ... but it looks like the JSON returned by your query isn't valid JSON  so decode won't work . You can confirm  JSON output with http://jsonlint.com/ by placing your request URL (http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?q=from:CM96YS%20to:CM96SN ) on a line .